# Create a Google Calendar Event In Developer Account

Tags: .net-core, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I have an requirement to Create an Calendar Event in one of the specified google account. I've been accessing the Api docs and It only shows how to create an event using the OAuth2 to create the Event in User's email account. But how to do this, using .Net Core, for a specified google account If I already have the access to username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant login to a google api using a login and password this is called client login and google turned this ability off in may 2015.

What you can do is create a service account.   A service account is a dummy user.  If you take the service account email address and share this calendar you want to access with the service account it will be able to create events.

```
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GoogleSamplecSharpSample.Calendarv3.Auth
{

    public static class ServiceAccountExample
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
        public static CalendarService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
                if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                    throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

                // For Json file
                if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
                {
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Service account Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
                {   // If its a P12 file

                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                    // Create the  Calendar service.
                    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountCalendarFailed", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code ripped from my calendar sample project [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)